# Using polygons to apply unique value to all raster cells within those polygons?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, polygon, masking

In ArcGIS 9.3, I have a raster file that I would like to "mask" with polygons, giving a single value to all the raster cells that overlap the polygons.

How can I do this?

Here's a screen shot, where the black polygons are my polygon layer, and the rest is raster-based.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a conditional statement. The issue with previous recommendations is that when you rasterize your polygons (which is necessary) the background, that does not contain polygons, will be NoData resulting in corresponding areas in the output also being NoData. You will need to set your analysis extent to your original raster and then set a background value (i.e., 0) to the rasterized polygon raster using SetNull. Once you have done this a conditional statement in the raster calculator will look something like this.

```
Con("praster" > 0, "praster", "OrgRaster")
```

"praster" is your rasterized ploygon feature class, with a background value of 0, and "OrgRaster" is the raster you wish to modify. This statement is saying that if praster is greater than 0 then assign values from praster else assign values from OrgRaster.

Answer (score 5):

You can rasterize (*ArcToolbox > Conversion Tools > To Raster*) your polygons, and then merge the two rasters with *Spatial Analyst Tools > Math > [Logical](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-math-logical-tools.htm) > Over*.

While rasterizing polygons, in the [Polygon To Raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/polygon-to-raster.htm) dialog window, you need to use *Environments -> Processing Extent* [Snap Raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/environments/snap-raster.htm) option, to get the cells correspondent to your initial raster.

Answer (score 1):

My approach was:

1. Perform a union with [Polygon] and [Study_Area]. Output: [Polygon_StudyArea_Union].
2. Edit values of the polygon in [Polygon_StudyArea_Union] to 0 and the resulting to 1.
3. Convert [Polygon_StudyArea_Union] to raster. Output: [Polygon_StudyArea_Union_Raster]
4. Perform a raster calculation:[The raster you want to edit] * [Polygon_StudyArea_Union_Raster]
5. Then reclassify to whichever value you want the zero (0) value to be.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the value raster to polygon,

then spatially join back to the zone polygon,

then convert the zone polygon to raster, keeping the field from the spatial join, and

then i think you should mosaic them together, keeping the 'top' raster, ie the zone raster values (rather than sum/min/max/median).