# How to reclassify raster inside polygon mask, leaving values outside as they are?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, reclassify, masking

I am in the final stages of a landcover classification and need to reclassify thematic raster values that are inside different polygon masks, while leaving the values outside as they are.

Can I do this with raster calculator? And, if so, how?

Comment: Apologies. I meant to add that I need to do this is in ArcGIS.

Comment: check this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40474/how-do-i-use-polygons-to-apply-a-unique-value-to-all-raster-cells-within-those-p

Comment: Thanks, but I need to *reclassify* specific classes inside the polygon mask, rather than make all the cells inside the mask one value.

Comment: I'm voting to keep it open, as I feel it is sufficiently different from the candidate question.

Comment: Reclassify the entire raster, then replace the original values by the reclassified values using `Con`. For details, [search our site for applications of `Con`](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=con%20raster).

Answer (score 8):

Because the [Raster Calculator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000z7000000) is a spatial analyst tool, you can utilize the [Mask environment](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001w0000001t000000).

[image]

From there, you can use a variety of commands to perform the reclassification:  common ones include [Con](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z00000005000000), [Pick](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z00000006000000), [Is Null](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000m8000000) and [Set Null](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z00000007000000), based on your needs.

[image]

To check if a specific spatial analyst tool honors the Mask environment, simply scroll down to the bottom of the help page and check the available environment settings.

[image]

Comment: Love the first illustration. It very clearly explains what is changed, however the answer itself doesn't address "leaving the outside values as they are", exactly. It leaves the outside values behind.