# Changing raster cells values inside of a polygon to the closest cells just outside the polygon!

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, polygon, nodata

I have been wrestling with this for a while and couldn't find out how I can do this. I want each cell of a raster inside of a polygon boundary to have the value of the closest cell just outside of the polygon.

I think the closest answer was the one at [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40474/using-polygons-to-apply-unique-value-to-all-raster-cells-within-those-polygons), but I couldn't apply it!

My plan was:

1. Use "Polygon to Raster" to change the polygon to a raster. The cells
   inside the polygon become 1 and the points outside of the
   polygon are nodata.
2. Use Con(IsNull(Raster),0,NULL) and assign it to Raster2
3. Add Raster1 and Raster2 to get nodata inside the polygon
4. It should be easy from here with nodata inside the polygon. We just use "Euclidean Allocation" and it does the job.

I'm stuck at step 2 and get an error:

> [SELECT * FROM VAT_Extent_RAS WHERE IsNull( "Value" )] Failed to
>   execute (Con).

Do you have any thoughts? Is there an easier way to do this?

**Update:**

I'll try to summarize my progress here. I want to change all raster cells inside the polygon to "nodata" while the raster cells outside of the polygon remain the same. I used polygon to raster function first. This gives me a raster with 0 cell inside the polygon and "nodata" outside of the polygon. What do I do next?

Comment: What error? Please provide error message.

Comment: [SELECT * FROM VAT_Extent_RAS WHERE IsNull( "Value" )]
Failed to execute (Con).

Comment: instead of *Con(IsNull(Raster),0,NULL)* try *Con(IsNull(Raster),0)* the NoData should be unstated. Sorry, I'm finding it a bit difficult to follow your process.

Comment: Hi Michael! I erased that. The problem is the "IsNull" section. I get the same error when I use IsNull("Value"). I am not sure why it is.

Comment: It's a raster conditional operator http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000m8000000 IsNull(Raster) true if the raster is null, false if the raster is not null. You can't use "Value" in there because that's a constant not a raster.

Comment: So I used IsNull("Extent_RAS"), IsNull(Extent_RAS), IsNull("Value"). None of them worked. The raster's name is "Extent_RAS" and it has a field named value. In the link that you sent thet use IsNull("degs"), where degs is a field, right?

Answer (score 5):

The [Euclidean Allocation tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000001m000000) can accept your polygon as input, but you are right you need to set the values inside the polygon to NoData for this tool to work, otherwise it will pick up the values that are already there.

First to feature to polygon, this will give values (any value, it doesn't matter, we're only interested in value or NoData) inside the polygon and NoData outside.

Now do [IsNull](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000m8000000) on the polygon raster, this will give you a raster with 1 outside the polygon and 0 inside the polygon. Hereafter called IsNullRaster. This can be done in a single statement but I want to use it twice so it's worth persisting it to disc.

[Con](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Con/009z00000005000000/) with the IsNullRaster: `Con(IsNullRaster,ValueRaster)` - now you have a raster that is null inside the polygon and contains values outside the polygon. I'll call this one ValueRasterHole. If this is giving you grief do something like `Con(IsNullRaster,ValueRaster,255)` and then use [Set Raster Properties](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000015z000000) to enforce 255 as the nodata value.

Set your [cell size](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Cell_Size/001w0000001s000000/), [extent](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Output_Extent/001w00000009000000/) and [snap raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001w0000000m000000) to the ValueRaster and do [Euclidean Allocation tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000001m000000) against the ValueRaster with the hole. This one is AllocatedRaster and will have values outside the polygon.

To merge the AllocatedRaster and the ValueRaster together use another Con with the IsNullRaster: `Con(IsNullRaster,ValueRaster,AllocatedRaster)` will fill in the hole in the polygon with the allocated raster.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough and complete solution. I used polygon to raster to make a raster from polygon. The values inside the polygon are zero. I guess the values outside of polygon are nodata (When I get the unique values just zero shows up and not nodata)

Anyways, from here, I try to use IsNull function to get 0 inside and 1 outside of the polygon. I get this error:

ERROR 010067: Error in executing grid expression.
Failed to execute (IsNull).

Do you have any idea where I'm messing it up?

Comment: +1 -- but you might want to research [`SetNull`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Set_Null/009z00000007000000/) because it will considerably streamline this workflow.

Comment: I have the same problem with SetNull. It gives me an error. A friend just recommened me to check the data type in the raster. It's long data and IsNull or SetNull don't like long values. That might be the problem.

Comment: I confirm that the problem was not using a integer base field when converting the polygon to raster.

Comment: Now I am going to use  Euclidean Allocation tool. I have a raster that has nodata inside the polygon and correct data outside the polygon. However, I cannot use Euclidean Allocation tool since it requires a source field. Although that is optional, it is forcing me to use something in the field and gives me error 000864 ("Source field: The input is not within the defined domain. ERROR 000889: Invalid field type"). Just a side note: When I right click on my raster, the "open attribute table" is off. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you guys so much. The problem solved. I just converted everythign to integer and after that it worked fine.