# Assign raster cells presence/absence values depending on whether polygon overlaps with cells

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, shapefile

I have a raster of continuous numeric values. A certain portion of said raster overlaps with a polygon of interest. I want to know which cells overlap, and assign values to the raster's attribute table corresponding to whether or not there is overlap (e.g. 0 for no overlap with polygon, 1 for overlap).

Ideally it would be great to be able to set an overlap threshold so that only raster cells where there is more than 50% overlap are assigned a "1". Not a must, but would be very helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/40474/8104?

Comment: Aaron, thanks for pointing me to that link.  I  ended up rasterizing the polygon to the extent of the original raster, and simply reclassified the rasterized polygon so that areas overlapping with the original raster were coded as 1 and the remaining cells were coded as 0.  A much simpler solution than I thought I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up rasterizing the polygon to the extent of the original raster, and simply reclassified the rasterized polygon so that areas overlapping with the original raster were coded as 1 and the remaining cells were coded as 0.