# Deleting specific pixels in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, pixel, con

I am trying to delete pixels in ArcGIS Pro, but could not get how to achieve it.

In the screenshot shared below:

The white pixels encircled in orange markers are the ones I want to delete.

I did try using the CON tool to keep only specific pixels but did not work.

[image]

Comment: You can't really delete pixels from a raster but do you mean that you would like to update them to have the same color than the neighboring pixels?

Comment: @user30184, my end goal is to make them transparent, to see the basemap, so though of removing them, will it be possible to somehow make them transparent? I did apply the No Data Mask on it for 255 values I had.

Comment: If you have set noData=255 then updating the value of those pixels into 255 will make them transparent if the viewer is configured to use noData.

Comment: Does this answer your question?: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/40474/8104. In your case, you would assign a NoData value to those cells.

Comment: Have you explored the [Pixel Editor](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/image-analyst/pixel-editor-in-arcgis-pro.htm) in ArcPro?

Comment: Yes, I did try exploring it, but could not get on how to remove these white pixels or make them transparent.